# MVC C# application, Json data in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

This may seem strange, but I would like to have my model contain Json data, which I could then use javascript to render html with the contents. My code looks like the following -

My Controller -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Object myObject = FillMyObjectWithData();

        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myObject);

        return View(json);
    }
```

My View -

```
    @model  string  /*Json data will be in the model*/
    <div>
        //standard html in here
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            doCoolStuff(@Model);
        });          
    </script>
```

I am getting the error - "*Illegal characters in path.*"

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: I believe you wish to use: return Json(SomeCollection,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) in your controller.

Comment: What does your generated html look like?

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Client side or server side? Also, I assume that doCoolStuff takes a JS object?

Comment: Hey Charlino, I am getting the error client side.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635383/illegal-characters-in-path-when-calling-the-index-view-from-my-controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in `return View(json);`

You are getting the wrong function overload `View(string)`, that is the overload to get a view by name. Try:

```
return View((object)json);
```

Also you want the raw JSON without HTML encoding:

```
 doCoolStuff(@Html.Raw(@Model));
```

Comment: Thanks fcuesta and James Lawruk!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@model  string  /*Json data will be in the model*/
<div>
    //standard html in here
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var temp = @model;
        doCoolStuff(temp);
    });          
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your motivation for attempting it this way? If you really want to return json you may be better served making an ajax request after the view/page loads and using javascript/jquery to render your UI with. This would be a good candidate for KnockoutJS.

Comment: Hey Jacob, Thanks for the response. I thought about doing this the way you suggest, but then I would have to make two calls to the server. One for the View, then one for the Json data.